# Npm lib unreachable from inside the docker container

Tags: docker, npm

`npm install` is failing from inside the container but when I am checking the lib path it's available and working from my browser, I am able to `wget` it from my server. And also why would other packages getting installed and only this one fails.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.721MB
Step 1/13 : FROM node:18.13-bullseye-slim as BASE
 ---> bbdad2b1501a
Step 2/13 : ARG ENVIRONMENT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7788e8b15d91
Step 3/13 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8228ffe0a1cb
Step 4/13 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ee8baec9eb9a
Step 5/13 : COPY package-lock.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f6a3cfe3557a
Step 6/13 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 7b7d5290caca
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-29T03_55_00_750Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am even able to `wget` from inside another docker container. So there shoudln't be any network issue, unless there's something with `node:18.13-bullseye-slim` image.

```
root@4517f9380b22:/app# wget https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz
--2023-09-29 04:23:04--  https://registry.npmjs.org/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz
Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 104.16.29.34, 104.16.27.34, 104.16.0.35, ...
Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|104.16.29.34|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2765 (2.7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz’

yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz                          100%[===================================================================================================>]   2.70K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-09-29 04:23:04 (33.3 MB/s) - ‘yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz’ saved [2765/2765]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker blocked on NPM install - Socket Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396537/docker-blocked-on-npm-install-socket-timeout)

Comment: Are you on a work computer or work network? Is there something in the `.npmrc` file in either container? `docker run -it node:18.13-bullseye-slim bash; mkdir hi; cd hi; npm install yocto-queue` works fine for me, so this is most likely something wrong with your network

Comment: @AndyRay I am on a work computer, and on that computer I am inside a on prem server (ubuntu). But from the same server, I am able to install other things (`python,node, npm install`),  also other python based images are working fine, I even logined to another docker image (python) from there `npmjs` is reachable